# Can't determine why maven is downloading a jar file

Tags: maven, log4j

I am having an issue with log4j-api. I have specified log4j-api:2.8.1 in my pom but when running a mvn clean install command, mvn keeps insisting that I need log4j-api:2.1. If i delete the log4j-api:2.1 directory from my .m2/repository and do the mvn clean install command, it will say it is downloading the 2.1 version.

Here's the weird thing: If I do a mvn dependency:tree there is no mention of version 2.1, only 2.8.1.

Anybody understand why mvn dependency:tree would say my project is NOT dependent on version 2.1 but then downloads the 2.1 version when I run mvn clean install?

Some other versions we are using in case somebody knows that something could be causing this:

- Spring Boot 1.2.1
- Spring Framework 4.1.6
- Elastic Java APIs 5.6.4

Comment: Take a look at the log output and check if the download is done by a dependency or by a plugin ...

Answer (score 0):

Get the dependency tree in verbose mode

`mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`

From [maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)

> More specifically, in verbose mode the dependency tree shows dependencies that were omitted for: being a duplicate of another; conflicting with another's version and/or scope; and introducing a cycle into the dependency tree.